# How to download google lens responses image with white effect on OCR texts?

Tags: html, css, web-scraping, google-image-search, inspect-element

When I upload an image to Google Lens using desktop browsers, after OCR and text extraction, a white effect is created by Google Lens around found texts and a black effect is created on the rest of the image components.
For example, i upload this image to Google Lens:

[image: my image]

then google lens responds with this image:

[image: google lens responses image]

If you pay attention to Google Lens response image, a white effect is created around the texts and the rest of image components are darker
If I normally right-click on Google Lens response image and select `save image` option, my original image that uploaded first will be downloaded for me. **but I want to download google lens response image which has a white color effect around the texts.**

I tried to download Google Lens response image by this options and I did not get a good result:

1. right-click on image and select save image option.
2. tested some browsers image downloader extensions.
3. tried to download image from inspect element.
4. tried to download google lens responses page and finding responses image from data folder of htm file.

I need any way to download Google Lens response image with applied effects.
Preferably, a way that I can convert 50 or 100 images to Google Lens responses images because it is very difficult to do manually and one by one for all of my images.